# Oozie Java action with Scala Code base JAR

Tags: java, scala, jar, oozie

I have created the workflow for Oozie to run the JAR file in JAVA action and I created the JAR by using MAVEN with scala code base. I am able to run the JAR on my cluster node where all my oozie job properties are defined by below mentioned commands. We already have oozie Shared Library in HDFS and uploading our JARs and JAVA code base JAR are working fine, except mine.

**Able to Run JAR with below Commands:**

java -cp tnlapidata-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.expedia.www.meso.tnlapidata.TnlApiGUIDData

java -jar tnlapidata-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

**Work Flow Action:**

[image]

**Failing with Error:**

*java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class >com.expedia.www.meso.tnlapidata.TnlApiGUIDData not found*

Comment: RTFM: the Oozie documentation clearly states that JARs should be downloaded from HDFS **via `<jar>` elements**; not `<file>` elements. That's because `<jar>` implies that the resource will be **added to the CLASSPATH** https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html >> by the way, did you inspect the YARN logs for your Oozie action?? Oozie is very verbose, and gives a detailed list of resources in the CLASSPATH. That's a good way to troubleshoot _"class not found"_ stuff.

Comment: As you can see there is > character in class name and it got resolved after correcting my configuration. Thanks for response.